# How to have graphical vizualisation of this table in R?

Tags: r, data-visualization, ggplot2

Actually, I have this kind of table I want to summarize into a graphic in R (preferably with ggplot2). Where the first three columns are the possible combinations of three methods (where 0 is absence and 1 presence) and the three last ones are the number of elements for each three methods.

[image]

I tried to resume this table into a figure, actually I tried Venn diagram, upset plot but as you see I have different values for each method in a given combination.

I wondered if you know some graphics which I could use to have graphical representation of this table. Examples are more than welcome.

Comment: Your three columns on the right only have nonzero entries in rows where the corresponding one of the three columns on the left has a "1" entry. Is that correct? If so, then it would rather argue for three $2\times 2$ tables, than for your large one.

Comment: I am extremely positive about graphics, but this seems a case where your table is as clear and as easy to think about as any graphic would be.

Comment: @NickCox Actually, I was trying to resume this table because I would like to use it into scientific publication. If you think it is as clear as I expected, probably I am using it  with features mentionned below

Comment: @StephanKolassa If I well understand your comment, I do not want to consider the three method independently. Which I guess, it is the case if I use the approach you are proposing. If I am wrong, please clarify your comment with an example.

Comment: It would be wrong to make a graphic out of this table. You should only do this when your story is 1000 words or more.

Answer (score 1):

As Nick Cox already said, it is already clear, but a possible addon might be a table with small graphics, for this, one can use formattable package with sparklines package

https://www.r-bloggers.com/2018/11/make-beautiful-tables-with-the-formattable-package/

Which gives us for example such a table with sparklines:

[image: table]

Possible sparklines could be:
[image: spark]

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I did not know sparkline package, it is look like I can improve my table. However, do you know if it is produced through ggplot functions? Actually, I am producing my panel of figures with ggpubr package which is only-compatible with ggplot figures.

Comment: The sparkline package can be seen as a standalone html widget: https://bart6114.github.io/sparklines/ and the sparklines itself base on jquery but the implementation is realtiveley easy as you can see

Comment: In Tufte's parlance, this example with sparklines has a remarkably large Lie Factor!  Would the package at least permit displaying all the plots on the same axes to enable accurate visual comparison?

Answer (score 0):

I am not really sure if that makes it more readable, but maybe you could just create a figure with boxes? Each line could then represent a column of your table. In general, I would check if the order in your column is the most reader-friendly. I am not familiar with your work, so for me, it is a bit difficult to read 0 0 1, then 0 1 0 and then 0 1 1. I would probably expect 1 0 0 as the third position, perhaps that does not makes sense for your case.

[image]